# Does the AUG | Akihabara Accept come from an anime? If so, which one?

Tags: identification-request

[image]

In Counter-Strike: Global Offensive a new skin was released called the Akihabara Accept. The description of the skin is:

> Powerful and accurate, the AUG scoped assault rifle compensates for
>   its long reload times with low spread and a high rate of fire. It has
>   been decorated with a heat transfer vinyl of an **anime magazine cover**.

So I'm curious, does this actually come from a real anime magazine cover? Or is this just some custom in-house work by Valve?  On the girl on the butt end of the gun the words "Fazik" are labelled on her uniform; perhaps it's part of the artist or something?

[image]

Here's an [imgur album with closeups of the skin in question](https://imgur.com/a/OFadr).

Comment: This was asked over on Gaming SE, and the answer was no. Check the comments: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/is-the-anime-gun-really-from-an-anime

Comment: @Matt So while it may not be from an anime, it does say it's from an anime magazine cover. But it doesn't specify it.

Comment: I suppose so - I was just going on what was discussed earlier. In any case, that other post has been deleted by the author, so an answer here will be useful.

Comment: Based from the Japanese texts on the skin itself, it's too related to CS:GO (or FPS) terms than general anime magazine: K/D (Kill/Death ratio), GET REKT, 1v5, and not to mention the title of the magazine itself: "CS:GO Accept". It looks more like a *parody* of (anime) magazine cover.

Answer (score 3):

Also, as mentioned by Matt, **it does not look like it comes from any specific manga or anime** and is just some random Japanese anime character put on there by Steam, hoping to get some money from otaku fans alike willing to pay huge amounts of money for just an anime skin.

---

<sub>Based on [comments on it at Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensiveTrade/comments/37ftv6/discussion_aug_akihabara_accept_screens/) and [steam itself](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AUG%20|%20Akihabara%20Accept%20%28Field-Tested%29). If it was based on something you would expected steam to promote it as such.</sub>

Comment: Do not forget that *promote* is not the same as *has the right*.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Aki Tanaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2516/aki-tanaka) it is probably a parody of an anime magazine. Valve is not allowed and will never use original artwork, covers or other illustrations that have been produced by somebody else.

The [Steam Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/workshop/) is the only platform where other people can upload their ideas for a skin, but before they can upload it they have to give Valve all rights for said artwork, confirming that the skin is their own work.

The *Akihabara Accept* is not a work from the workshop and therefore has been made by Valve.

Descriptions like the one you posted:

> It has been decorated with a heat transfer vinyl of an anime magazine cover.

are only to roughly indicate how the skin has been created. It is similar to the *Kami* skin which has a manga page painted on it.

> It has been painted using a hydrographic in a Japanese manga pattern.